# Create Virtual Server Dynamically Using PHP

Tags: php, networking, server

I am creating a webapp for multiple companies to use but i don't want all to be login through one place so i want to create virtual servers for every client whenever i want to add them. So Anyone Have Idea How I Would Be Able To Do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Per [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) :

**PHP Built-in web server**

As of PHP 5.4.0, the CLI SAPI provides a built-in web server.

The web server runs a only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.

Example #1 Starting the web server

```
$ cd ~/public_html
$ php -S localhost:8000
```

The terminal will show:

```
PHP 5.4.0 Development Server started at Thu Jul 21 10:43:28 2011
Listening on localhost:8000
Document root is /home/me/public_html
Press Ctrl-C to quit
```

**Note :** This web server was designed to aid application development. It may also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.

**Now, About Dynamically Creating Server :**

1. Create a Loop PHP `foreach` or `while`
2. Using [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)
3. Pass your **dynamic directory name** instead of `~/public_html`
4. Pass your **dynamic Port Number** instead of `8000`

Hope This may help you.

Comment: Thank You It Helped Me A Lot,
Now I Would Be Able To Complete The Project Nicer Way...

Answer (score -1):

Try Creating [PHP Bult-in Server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) Using :

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Comment: Thank You For Replying....
But I Was Wanted To Do All Things Dynamically...